# Configuration of embedded Neo4j to run APOC procedures

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have cypher queries that make use of APOC functions. It works without problem if running the app directly but I would also like to test those queries. I tried to use [following](https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-examples-and-tips/blob/master/examples/testing-ogm-against-embedded-with-apoc/src/test/java/org/neo4j/tips/testing/testing_ogm_against_embedded_with_apoc/ApplicationTests.java#L53-L67) approach but getting an exception `Unknown function 'apoc.coll.toSet'`

My sample test class:

```
public class ApocTest {
    private static Neo4j neo4j;
    private static Driver driver;

    @BeforeAll
    static void initializeNeo4j() {
        // Make sure that the plugins folder is listed in -cp
        Path pluginDirContainingApocJar = Paths.get("src/main/resources/neo4j-plugins/");

        if (!Files.exists(pluginDirContainingApocJar)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid path to plugins directory");
        }

        neo4j = Neo4jBuilders
                .newInProcessBuilder()
                .withDisabledServer()
                .withFixture("CREATE (p1:Person)-[:knows]->(p2:Person)-[:knows]->(p3:Person)")
                .withConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.plugin_dir, pluginDirContainingApocJar)
                .withConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.procedure_unrestricted, List.of("apoc.*"))
                .build();
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver(neo4j.boltURI(), AuthTokens.none());
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void stopNeo4j() {
        driver.close();
        neo4j.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testApoc(){
        String query = "MATCH path=()-[:knows*2]->()\n" +
                       "RETURN apoc.coll.toSet(nodes(path)) AS nodesSet";
        List<Object> nodesSet = driver.session()
                .beginTransaction()
                .run(query)
                .single()
                .get("nodesSet")
                .asList();
        assertEquals(3, nodesSet.size());
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix that?

[This sample project on the github](https://github.com/Lukasmp3/neo4j-apoc-testing)

Versions:

- neo4j-java-driver: 4.1.1
- neo4j-harness 4.1.6
- org.neo4j.procedure: 4.1.0.5

### Update:

So I tried to update:

```
Path pluginDirContainingApocJar = new File(
                ApocConfig.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI())
                .getParentFile().toPath();
```

That means that I don't need to manipulate with apoc jars, right?
But I'm still getting error:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry@27dc627a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unable to set up injection for procedure `CypherProcedures`, the field `cypherProceduresHandler` has type `class apoc.custom.CypherProceduresHandler` which is not a known injectable component.".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:463)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:189)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ComponentInjectionException: Unable to set up injection for procedure `CypherProcedures`, the field `cypherProceduresHandler` has type `class apoc.custom.CypherProceduresHandler` which is not a known injectable component.
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.FieldInjections.createInjector(FieldInjections.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.FieldInjections.setters(FieldInjections.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ProcedureCompiler.java:264)
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ProcedureCompiler.java:226)
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:114)
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:85)
    at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.start(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:342)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442)
    ... 60 more
```

### Update 2 - working on 4.0:

For some reason downgrade to Neo4j 4.0, same version as in [recommended](https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-examples-and-tips/blob/master/examples/testing-ogm-against-embedded-with-apoc/src/test/java/org/neo4j/tips/testing/testing_ogm_against_embedded_with_apoc/ApplicationTests.java#L53), was enough to make it working. Now I won't spend more time to try to run it on Neo4j 4.1/4.2.

[My code](https://github.com/Lukasmp3/neo4j-apoc-testing)

Comment: Hi, do you have updates? Do you get a working build with versions >= 4.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the way the path to the plugin directory was created. There's an example from Michael Simons here that explains using the neo4j classloader: https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-examples-and-tips/blob/master/examples/testing-ogm-against-embedded-with-apoc/src/test/java/org/neo4j/tips/testing/testing_ogm_against_embedded_with_apoc/ApplicationTests.java#L53

Comment: I tried it, but wasn't successful, so I updated original answer.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for trying that, will see if I can check what's changed in later versions

Comment: Sure, thanks, let me know if you find some nice ways to do it for later versions.